# Can't open Yoast SEO (WordPress) plugin Search Console (page not found)

Tags: wordpress, yoast

On hosting Yoast plugin is not working properly in admin (if you click the Search Console item on the menu, or try to run any of the configuration wizards you get a 404).
So it must open pages `.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_search_console&tab=settings` and `.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_configurator` but for some reason show that page is not found.
On the other hand on my local host everything is work correct!
What I tried to do with no success:

1. Refresh WP
2. Refresh Yoast plugin.
3. Deactivate other plugins.
4. Uninstall and install again Yoast plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe a very silly question, but in your example you are linking to `/admin.php`. Could you possibly have forgotten the `/wp-admin` prefix in the URL?

Comment: I've corrected, I hope it is help.

Comment: I've tested with a clean setup with latest WP (4.7.1) and last version of Yoast, so it can't be vendor related.

Comment: I tested it in the same way with same result. Can it be about hosting?